# Is ssl protocol TLS1.3 can be enabled in apache 2.2 or 2.4?

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services, nginx

Anyone please let me know if sslprotocol TLS1.3 can be enabled in apache 2.2 or 2.4.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252949/is-it-possible-to-use-tlsv1-3-in-apache-2-4

Answer (score 2):

There is a backport available for the 2.4 branch: [https://pastebin.com/raw/7hs9WgSH]

Apply this patch to the current (2.4.33) sources and then compile it together with openssl1.1.1-pre headers. Tested and working with Debian sources, openssl1.1.1 is available in unstable.
To get TLSv1.3 finally enabled, you need to change your ssl config to something like this:

```
SSLCipherSuite TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:...
SSLProtocol TLSv1.3 +TLSv1.2
```

Client tested with current nss libs togehter with Waterfox.

Comment: How do you apply the patch?  Can you provide some step by step directions on this?  Does this require the mod-nss extension as well?

Comment: Please see my new posted answer.

About your question on mod-nss, no of course you don't need this on apache httpd side. With my initial post I just tried to say clearly that if you want to use Waterfox as a client, you need updated nss libs to be able to use tlsv1.3. With nightly Firefox or Chrome you won't need anything beside enabling v1.3 in those clients.

Answer (score 0):

The unofficial backport should soon be obsolete. Apache httpd team planned to release 2.4.36 with openssl 1.1.1 and tlsv1.3 support.
Due to an issue with h2 this has been stopped, you can read more about it here:
[lists.apache.org/](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/1ebfadad8f34cdf8520e2b9771cd8b8ca1a11b8d6d416b41e73c2687@%3Cdev.httpd.apache.org%3E)

If you still want to compile by yourself, you can

- either check out the source via [github](https://github.com/apache/httpd/tree/2.4.36) (tag: 2.4.36)
- or download the [source](https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/httpd/) directly from apache dist server (content not static, will no longer be present as soon as an update was uploaded)

Maybe you want to apply the h2 fix from [rev 1843954](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1843954)